# how to only this radio button change this div tab changed

Tags: jquery

I have two form, each with a radio button to change tabs on their own page, but these two blocks do not work tab when placed on the a page.
i use each for nationality_checkbox and get this input name put in`$('input:radio[name="nationality"]')`  name but dont work

```
https://jsfiddle.net/djyofpx7/
```

EDIT 1

i change my jquery but i cannot get attr name and result is undefined

```
$('.nationality_checkbox').next().next().each(function(i, obj) {


    var atrname = $(this).find('input').attr('name');


    $('input:radio[name=' + atrname + ']').change(

        function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'usa') {

                $(this).find('.usa').show();
                $(this).find('.nousa').hide();

            } else if ($(this).val() == 'non-usa') {

                $(this).find('.nousa').show();
                $(this).find('.usa').hide();


            }
        }
    );



});


https://jsfiddle.net/mp4r31ac/1/
```

Comment: that is because you have used the same `name` attribute value. In the first form, let both the radios have `name="nationality1"` and in the second form let it be `name="nationality2"`

Comment: @illusion i change this but not work how to foreach in name ?Is this solution right or is there another solution?https://jsfiddle.net/10adwuL3/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that: for example in this line `$('.usa').show();`, you are referencing to ALL objects with class name 'usa'. So it will show ALL THE ELEMENTS who have class as 'usa' and similar for `$('.nousa').hide();`.

To solve this give them distinct class names, or probably give them unique IDs and then reference them using these ids in jquery.

Secondly, since there are two groups of radio buttons, the simplest option is to reference them differently and add event handlers for both of them, in which you have also given distinct class names for `'usa'` and `'nousa'`...

This should do it.

For a dynamic approach, when you add new elements:

```js
$(".passengers-info-box").each(function(i, obj) {
  var child_inp = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]');
  var parent = this;
  child_inp.change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'usa') {
      $(parent).find('.usa').show();
      $(parent).find('.nousa').hide();
    } else if ($(this).val() == 'non-usa') {
      $(parent).find('.nousa').show();
      $(parent).find('.usa').hide();
    }
  })
})
```

But when you add elements dynamically, you need to add the event handlers again...

Comment: the same fiddle right? I cant see the changes there...

Comment: As i said, it is easiest to add two event handlers...

Comment: do you want to make it like a single jquery code? yes i

Comment: how to add two event handlers ? can you help me a  example? i'm understand

Comment: please help me for a single jquery code because i add every item with appendchild

Comment: Thank you very much I desperately need this function <3

Comment: check the new javascript code, use this instead of your code...

Comment: tanx you bro i used this fn , tworks normally but   for append not work way ?  https://jsfiddle.net/8ob9ftgz/2/

Comment: name="nationality44" >> For example, I know the names need to be changed

Comment: After appending just COPY the code that registers the event handler. This works. But the best way would be to register the events by using HTML ID values, so that when you register them again using the class name, it wont re-register...

Comment: how to change by id? i'm understand sooryy :(

Comment: This is the simplest way to do but not the best: https://jsfiddle.net/manas99/voqu0re9/9/